# OneHot/Dummy Encoding List in a Dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, machine-learning, scikit-learn, one-hot-encoding

Attempting to set up a DF for an ML model, and I'm having trouble with one of the columns that contains data like this:

| Name | Reasons |
| --- | --- |
| Name1 | Reason1, Reason2, Reason3 |
| Name2 | Reason2, Reason4, Reason99 |
| Name3 | None |
| Name4 | Reason3, Reason12 |

The list in the Reasons column is comma delimited, and can contain anywhere from 0 (labeled as 'None') to 50+ values.

I need to do two steps:

1. Remove specific reasons from the above column, that I have stored in a separate df:

| Index | Reason |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | Reason1 |
| 3 | Reason3 |
| 7 | Reason7 |
| 8 | Reason8 |

To get a result similar to:

| Name | Reasons |
| --- | --- |
| Name1 | Reason2 |
| Name2 | Reason2, Reason4, Reason99 |
| Name3 | None |
| Name4 | Reason12 |

2. One Hot Encode the simplified table as follows:

| Name | Reason2 | Reason4 | Reason12 | **** |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Name1 | 1 | 0 | 0 |  |
| Name2 | 1 | 1 | 0 |  |
| Name3 | 0 | 0 | 0 |  |
| Name4 | 0 | 0 | 1 |  |

There are other columns in the df that should remain unchanged in the process.

For Part 1, I've been stumped for finding any method that makes sense, even though it seems like it should be simple.

For Part 2, I've tried a Sklearn OneHotEncoder:

```
OneHot = OneHotEncoder(
    categories='auto',  # Categories per feature
    drop=None, # Whether to drop one of the features
    sparse=False, # Will return sparse matrix if set True
    #dtype=int, #Preferred output as integer 0 or 1
    handle_unknown='error' # Whether to raise an error 
)       

transformer = make_column_transformer(
    (OneHot, ['Reasons']),
    remainder='passthrough')

transformed = transformer.fit_transform(df)
result = pd.DataFrame(
    transformed, 
    columns=transformer.get_feature_names_out()
)
```

*Which didn't separate the reasons to encode as needed. *

Also tried get_dummies with a string function:

```
result = df['Reasons'].str.get_dummies()
```

*Which keeps crashing the kernel.*

How can I overcome my challenges above? About at my wits end trying to get this working correctly. My target dataset is millions of rows, efficiency is a definite plus.